# Mcafee Conflict with Windows 7 and Bradford Persistent Agent

Tags: windows-7

My college network requires Bradford Persistent Agent and Mcafee Virus Software 8.7i. The Bradford Persistent Agent basically checks to make sure Mcafee is running and updated, and reports this status to the network. If it is configured incorrectly, I cannot access the Internet. Right now, I am running off of the device network, (iPod/iPhone WiFi) which is considerably slower and doesn't enable me to use my Ethernet cable.

With Windows Vista, everything was configured correctly. After my upgrade to Windows 7, Bradford Persistent Agent isn't registering the fact that Mcafee is installed and updated. Also, Windows Security Center isn't properly registering Mcafee as well, it knows that it is installed but can't read information reports from it.

I have tried running the install files and the programs themselves in several configurations of compatibility modes, to no avail.  I think this is a problem with Mcafee. Is there a solution?

**Solution** (for me):

1. Windows Button -> type "services" -> click "services" icon at top of start menu
2. Navigate to Bradford Persistant Agent -> select Restart Service
3. Bradford Agent now recognized Mcafee (in my situation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bradford persisent agent works one hundred percent with win7 and Mcafee. (I support it at my own Helpdesk).

After you install the Bradford Persistent Agent, do you get the popup (From bradford) to ask you to login? If no, uninstall Bradford and disable any Firewall you have running.

Also, try restarting the Bradford Agent service (Search for services in the start menu and open services, look for Bradford and right-click and hit restart. Also definitely try reinstalling.

Next question, when you hit rescan on the bradford page, does the popup come up with the loading bar going across? If it does, Does the bar go all the way across or does it just jump to the end half way through.

Also, tell him, "look I have McAfee set to auto Update, and Bradford installed." He can manually add you to the network so that you have the internet in the mean time.

Finally, You could try a different Anti-Virus, like AVG, Comodo or Avira. Bradford supports tons of Anti-Virus Software. (You can download it to your Jump Drive from a different computer) Other software can still update through the Bradford network.

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: the Bradford Persistent Agent is licensed to my College, and so it has never required a manual login. When you first try to connect to the network (without the agent) it puts you in a "remediation" network and says you must download the Agent. once it is downloaded, it is supposed to register that mcafee is running and updated (it did this when I had vista). I had no interactions with the agent besides installing to get it to work before (on vista).

Comment: Yes, I know this. Ok, your college may not require you to login, but usually the remediation network has a log in page in order to download the file. 

Did you try restarting the Bradford services? 

By adding you "Manually" I meant,that at our helpdesk we recongize that it may not work all the time, and we add some of our users manually.For example, Norton 2010 is not recognized by BPA, and we add manually added people. What does the remediation tell you you failed on?

Comment: restarting the system service worked. many thanks to you

Comment: NP, glad i could help, BPA is no fun some times :)


now just image it to be your job
lol

Answer (score 0):

Bradford Networks seems like a serious company, so it would astound me to find out that they aren't compatible with Windows 7. Evidently, the version you had in Vista isn't compatible with Windows 7.

IMHO, you should get in touch with the campus network administrator and ask for a Bradford Persistent Agent version for Windows 7. If he doesn't have it, he should get in touch with their Support. Ask also for installation instructions : whether you need to uninstall the old version before installing the new or just upgrade.

Comment: I will try asking him about a newer version to see if he has looked into the problem. I have already dealt with him one-on-one a few times with him trying to help me configure it, but with no luck.

Comment: You can also try to find the .exe file of Bradford Persistent Agent, right-click it, then Properties, Compatibility tab, check "Run this program..." and choose from the drop-down list "Windows Vista (service pack 2)".

Comment: already tried that harrymc

Comment: In that case only a new Win7 version will do the job.

Comment: I have the newest version. It is supposed to support windows 7.